# ViewDestroyedError when click closing Angular2-notification in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm getting this error when I click the notification for close.it seems to occur randomly.

> zone.js:196 Uncaught Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a
>   destroyed view: detectChanges
>           at viewDestroyedError (core.js:9540)
>           at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14336)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
>           at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
>           at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14277)
>           at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges
>   (core.js:11300)
>           at angular2-notifications.umd.js:531
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:392)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:391)

this error hits Many times(appx 1667 times) in my app because it executes change detection life cycle hooks.

Please help me to out form this if any one have idea to solve this issue.

[Angular2-Notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (!this.changeDetectorRef['destroyed']) {
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```